# User search filter with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In useEffect with fetch(api), I have set [search].
This shows "loading..." every time I type something in the input box and I have to click on the box to type next word/number.

I'd like to know how I can avoid it so that I can keep typing without choosing the box every single letter I typed.

I have JSON data which has "login" as the username.
It would be appreciated if I could get help.

App.js file:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import './App.css';
import UserDetails from "./UserDetails"

function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!search) {
      return;
    }
    setLoading(true);

    fetch(`https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${search}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        setUsers(res.items);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [search]); // every time search changes, we call the fn

  if(loading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>
  }

  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Github user searcher</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search"
        onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)}
        value={search}
      />

      {users.map((user, name) => (  // {}you have ti return inthis fn, () using this return directly
        <UserDetails
          key={name}
          {...user}
        />
      ))}

    </div>
  )

};

export default App;
```

UserDetails.js file:

```
import React from "react"

function UserDetails(props) {
  return(
    <div>
      {props.login}
    </div>
  )
}

export default UserDetails
```

Comment: Its because your are setting `loading` true. So as input changes. It set `true` and the `false`. What do you want when user is typing?

Comment: yes @ShubhamVerma is right, every time you type something, `search` is modified, so your effect is called, and you `setLoading(true)`, si it destroys all your input, userDetails etc, and mounts the `p` tag. Then after `setLoading(false)` a **new** input is mounted = you have lost the focus.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution would be to debounce setSearch, that way it would execute the search only after user stops typing (delayed execution)

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import './App.css';
import UserDetails from "./UserDetails"

function debounce(callback, wait) {
  let timeout
  return (...args) => {
    const context = this
    clearTimeout(timeout)
    timeout = setTimeout(() => callback.apply(context, args), wait)
  }
}

function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  // this will create a new function that will execute setSearch when it wasn't called for 200 ms
  const debouncedSetSearch = debounce((...args) => setSearch(...args), 200);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!search) {
      return;
    }
    setLoading(true);

    fetch(`https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${search}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        setUsers(res.items);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [search]); // every time search changes, we call the fn

  if(loading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>
  }

  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Github user searcher</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search"
        onChange={e => debouncedSetSearch(e.target.value)}
        value={search}
      />

      {users.map((user, name) => (  // {}you have ti return inthis fn, () using this return directly
        <UserDetails
          key={name}
          {...user}
        />
      ))}

    </div>
  )

};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, you might consider not to hide search input when searching. Something like:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import UserDetails from './UserDetails'

function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!search) {
      return
    }

    setLoading(true)

    const abortController = new AbortController()

    fetch(`https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${search}`, {
      signal: abortController.signal,
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        setUsers(res.items)
        setLoading(false)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })

    // Abort previously created Fetch request
    // if search param has been changed in order
    // not to overload server with redundant requests
    return () => {
      abortController.abort()
    }
  }, [search]) // every time search changes, we call the fn

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Github user searcher</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search"
        onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
        value={search}
      />

      {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}

      {!loading &&
        users.map((
          user,
          name // {}you have ti return inthis fn, () using this return directly
        ) => <UserDetails key={name} {...user} />)}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

You can also consider setting up focus with the help of `ref`, but the flickering search box might provide an unpleasant user experience.

UPD

I updated the example snippet with aborting redundant requests.

Comment: Moreover I would `debounce` the effect, easy to do with a `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`.
After your edit : Interesting, the abort thing. `axios` has a similar mechanism `cancelToken` for those who would be interested.

Answer (score 0):

I used setTimeout. It is worked too.

[Look my Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-bash-vr9t1?file=/public/index.html)